# Cross Project Compare option in Data Stage 9.1

Tags: data-warehouse, datastage, istool

There is a utility called Cross Project compare in the Data Stage designer. using the cross project compare utility I can compare two jobs (for eg. two parallel jobs) from different environments (for eg dev vs prod). I wondered if there is any command line with istool for the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be achieved using the utility diffapicmdline.exe. Following is the syntax for the same:`C:\IBM\InformationServer91\Clients\Classic\diffapicmdline.exe /lhscd "/d=server_name:port /h=server /u=user_id /p=password other_server_project %%i" /rhscd "/d=other_server /h=other_server /u=user_name /p=password otherserver/project .isx" /t Job /ot html /ol E:\compare_output_isxname.html`